# Error when testing iOS 5 app in Deployment Target 4.2

Tags: ios5, ios4, storyboard, target

i have made an application with storyboard and the new iOS 5 feature like this:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navigationBarImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

if i try to test the app Deployment Target to 4.2 for the user that still have that firmware, i receive an error in the line i write above, so my question is how i can test my app on 4.2 device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For something which only works on iOS 5, you can do the following.

You can try to get the version by this way :
`float version = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];`

And you try which version the user has before your code :

```
if (version >= 5.0) { your code }
```

Comment: yes i think it's better in this way, you know how i can do the line of code i write above in question in ios4?

Comment: You can find the situation before 5.0 there : http://www.accella.net/custom-uinavigationbar/
You have to use the old drawRect method in order to do it.